# Script ends on UserDialog

Tags: vba

I know this code works on some computers (I don't have access to them).

Unfortunately, when I run this code, It doesn't show any window. 
It just stop working on the line: `wynik = WordBasic.Dialog.UserDialog(wybor)`.

It seems like script ends there. Can anyone tell me what is wrong?

```
WordBasic.BeginDialog 350, 208, "Otwórz aktualizację", "WczytajRozpiskę.fundial"
    WordBasic.ListBox 12, 20, 100, 180, Tomy__$(), "Tomy"
    WordBasic.ListBox 139, 20, 100, 180, Aktual__$(), "Aktual"
    WordBasic.Text 12, 5, 39, 13, "Tom:", "Teks1"
    WordBasic.Text 139, 5, 99, 13, "Aktualizacja:", "Teks2"
    WordBasic.OKButton 249, 149, 88, 21
    WordBasic.CancelButton 249, 179, 88, 21
    If red$ = "1" Then WordBasic.PushButton 252, 19, 88, 21, "Zest.", "Wcis1"
WordBasic.EndDialog

Dim wybor As Object
Set wybor = WordBasic.CurValues.UserDialog
WordBasic.DisableInput 1
wynik = WordBasic.Dialog.UserDialog(wybor)
WordBasic.DisableInput 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actualy, problem was in WczytajRozpiskę.fundial function...